# '|' types '\' instead

Tags: external-keyboard

I recently got a Logitech K380 (Turkish Q layout).
When I type '|' (Alt Gr + <) it types '\' instead.

I've already checked for:

- Mismatched layouts: but all other keys (including '\', which is bound to AltGr + *) type properly.
- Defective Keyboard: but keyboard works fine on a Windows PC.

I've tested it on two different devices, one with KitKat and another with Lineage 16. Both have the problem.

A possibly useful thing I found was that if I were on the UK layout, the keys I pressed would print '\'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Minutes after asking this question, I started trying random combinations in order to see if anything else was out of place.

Turns out, Android decided that AltGr + - was a better shortcut for '|'.